# External hard disk OS installation

Tags: windows-7, windows

Im trying to install and use windows 7 on external hdd for learning practice. Without disturbing my host os, is that possible?

Comment: I have external seagate hdd. Wanna use it as extension to my internal HD or want to install OS separately on external hdd.  Altogether I want to separate my lappy with external hdd used for office or technology learning purpose

Comment: Windows can't be installed in external drives.

Comment: You would have to use something like a RAID array in order to combine the drives, and you aren't able to use an external drive for Windows boot. There are tools like WinToUSB that may work, but for the most part this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7, there is no decent way to boot it from a USB drive except you are installing a Windows 7 PE.

However, for Windows 8 and Windows 10 **Enterprise** and **Education** versions, there is a feature called [Windows To Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go) which allows it been booted from external drive.

If you only want to do some experiments without affecting your host OS. Try **virtualization**, you can get *VirtalBox* or use *Hyper-V* to install a guest OS.